# doing something vs something doing

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage, gerunds

Is there any kind of a rule about using either form? For example:

- managing people vs people managing
- negotiating a contract vs contract negotiating
- writing documentation vs documentation writing

Comment: "Today I am writing documentation. I am not very good at documentation writing" The first refers to an activity, the second identifies a particular type of writing. We would be more likely to speak of _people management_,as a particular branch of management skills.

Comment: And we would usually say _contract negotiation_ not _negotiating_